# Handling multiple languages without delay in Android's TTS

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have this problem: I'd like to let the TTS speak an English sentence with foreign words in it (for instance, Italian).
The problem is that, after instancing a `TextToSpeech` class, every time I change language, it takes several seconds to load, and this is unacceptable since the sentence needs to be as fluid as possible.
I also tried instancing more than one `TextToSpeech`, but the results are pretty much identical.

I wasn't able to find something on Google, aside from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994354/android-two-instances-of-text-to-speech-work-very-slowly) question, which was unhelpful.

Is there at all a way to achive this? How?

Thanks in advance,
Mauro.

Comment: Any solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another TTS engine. `Ivona TTS` switch between languages pretty fast. Sometime at the start it is a little bit slow to switch, but after the first sentence it is fine.

Comment: It could be a solution, but I don't want to force my users to use a particular TTS Engine.

Comment: I used Ivona and it is fast, I do not know about others. You definitely cannot use Google TTS for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Checked out Ivona. It does not contain the languages I need.

Comment: There are many other TTS engines, check them out for the language you need and see which one is the better one.